# Can I permanently store items somewhere?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In good old CRPG tradition I'm taking anything that isn't nailed down with me. I've got half a forest worth of assorted plants and more iron ore and other crafting materials than any normal human could carry.

Now, at some point I'm reaching the weight limit of my inventory, but I really don't want to throw any crafting and alchemy ingredients away. Is there a place where I can permanently store items so I don't have to carry them around?

In the first game you could do that generally in inns, but I'm now at the first Inn in the game and see no option to store my items.

Comment: What's the C mean in CRPG?  I've heard of WRPG and JRPG...

Comment: @StrixVaria computer

Comment: @StrixVaria Computer RPG as opposed to Pen&Paper. WFRPG (Warhammer Fantasy...) is a one brand of pen&paper kind, JRPG is a sub-genre of CRPG (Japaneese).

Comment: This is a question for which I, too, need an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Witcher 2 the storage system do not belongs to Inn keepers but some other people.
Like for your case in Flotsam, the storage is set to a man down-stair sitting inside a bar or walking around it. (just left turn when you enter the room with fighting area)
And in Act 2, is the dwarf walking around or sitting in front of the whore camp's fire.

Answer (score 1):

As for the permanent storage, I understand there is none: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/59155994

Comment: Guess you just have to craft some of it away?

Comment: @Sjohnston I tried to do that once, thinking that all the plants I was carrying around would be lighter once I combined them into potions and bombs. However, as plants weigh 0 and potions and bombs do *not*, I just made the problem worse. :(